# Wildcard in Makefile doesn't do anything

Tags: rhel, kernel-modules, wildcards, make

I'm trying to compile a kernel module named DAHDI in a FreePBX (RHEL). I get the following make output error:

```
You do not appear to have the sources for the 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 kernel installed.
```

But I don't think that is the problem, cuz I already checked my kernel version, headers, config file and they all match. In the Makefile, I have this block:

```
KCONFIG:=$(KSRC)/.config
ifneq (,$(wildcard $(KCONFIG)))
  HAS_KSRC:=yes
  include $(KCONFIG)
else
  HAS_KSRC:=no
endif
```

`$(KCONFIG)` returns "/.config". `$(HAS_KSRC)` return "no". `$(wildcard $(KCONFIG))` doesn't return anything. This error comes from `ifeq (no,$(HAS_KSRC))`. In other words, it finds the kernel config file until it applies the "wildcard".

What does this wildcard (command??) do?

```
# cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@kbuilder.bsys.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Jun 18 16:35:19 UTC 2019
```

Comment: It expands its argument as a shell filename globbing pattern. Since your variable `$(KSRC)` is empty, the pattern resolves as `/.config`, and since that pathname does not exist on your system, `HAS_KSRC` is set to `no`. The solution, it seems, is to make sure that `KSRC` is set correctly, or to make sure that the sources are installed properly and that `/.config` exists (with the correct contents). As I'm not on Linux, I have no way of testing this and will thus not turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you have the source tree but it is currently unconfigured (that's why `.config` is missing).

Try:

1. To copy /boot/config- to ${KSRC}/.config

or

2. To run `make oldconfig` from kernel source-tree